# Counting rows and storing value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have been trying to store a value in a variable, which depends on what value is returned from the database.
Essentially, I'm wanting it to count how many Rooms there is, depending on the room type, and store it in a variable to be used elsewhere.

What I have is:

```
                DLDbContext context = new DLDbContext();
            //Counts how many versions of that room exists
            int RoomTypes = (from u in context.Room where u.type == ddlRoomType.SelectedItem.ToString() select u).Count();
```

The error thats appears is:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.

ddlRoomType is a drop down list, where the person is able to choose a Room Type, and depending on what they choose, it'll be searched through the database for how many of those rooms that actually exist.

Comment: That error doesn't sound like it's coming from the code posted.  Nothing in the code posted is trying to create a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are implicitly using `LINQ to Entities` on this line:

```
(from u in context.Room where u.type == ddlRoomType.SelectedItem.ToString() select u).Count()
```

`LINQ to Entities` need to convert your code into SQL. In order to do so, `ddlRoomType.SelectedItem.ToString()` needs to be converted to a `constant` so it can be included in the SQL. Entity Framework cannot convert this into a constant, specially because it doesn't know what kind of processing happens in the `toString` method. Do you understand it? The `toString()` method needs to be evaluated by C#, without evaluating it, it can't become a constant so it can be included in the SQL.

Try this instead:

```
DLDbContext context = new DLDbContext();
//Counts how many versions of that room exists
var roomType = ddlRoomType.SelectedItem.ToString();
int RoomTypes = (from u in context.Room where u.type == roomType select u).Count();
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help. I understand it a lot more now. This has fixed the issue as of right now (got another issue which is stopping it from working, but yeah, that'll work). Thank you!

Comment: Personally I would recommend to use Lambda expressions for LINQ expressions. The last row would become `var roomTypes = context.Room.Where(u => u.type == roomType).Count();` which is both shorter and more understandable.

Comment: Thank you Kaspars also for your input. I'll put both to use at separate occasions. I'm much more familiar with the way that andrerpena used, however, I think knowing both ways would help in the future.